# WooCommerce/WordPress Illegal String Offset

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been scratching my head on this one for a day now. Various searching through Google, WordPress, and StackOverflow have given me leads, but as I am not anything more than a beginner PHP guy that can only really change some things around, I am completely stumped. I apologize if this error is similar to other questions that have been asked, but I can't find a solution to my particular issue. I have support tickets with both WordPress and the theme developer, but I haven't found a solution yet. Here is the isse:

I am having an issue with a website that I am working on for a family member. I was trying to change the size of the product image in WooCommerce, so I made edits to the woocommerce.php file, changing the woocommerce_single_image_width size. After doing that, I get this "Illegal string" error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'crop' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 812
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 822
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 823
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'crop' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 824
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 828
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 828
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'crop' in
>   /home/wp_tnn5rz/funstickups.com/wp-content/themes/bazar-child/theme/woocommerce.php
>   on line 828

After doing some research, I found that this is more of an error, but since I have made the changes, I am unable to upload photos, or view my media in grid view (it works in list view though).

I downloaded the regenerate thumbnails plugin, but it told me that the action had failed. The images are small.. 566x3-something, so I don't think that it is caused by the size of the image.

In a last ditch effort, I deleted all of the products and decided to try it over, but I can't upload the images now, so I'm completely stuck.

The url is https://www.funstickups.com

Thanks you in advance!

Angelo

Here is the code from woocommerce.php (lines 803-832) where the errors are coming from.

```
function yit_get_featured_image_size() {

$element['width']   = "160";
$element['height'] = "160";
$element['crop']    = 1;

$element = get_option( 'shop_featured_image_size', $element );

$crop            = WC_Admin_Settings::get_option( 'shop_featured_image_size' . '[crop]' );
$element['crop'] = ( $crop == 'on' || $crop == '1' ) ? 1 : 0;

return  $element;
}

function yit_add_featured_image_size($images) {

$element = yit_get_featured_image_size();

if ( ! is_array( $element ) ) {
    $element['width']   = "160";
    $element['height'] = "160";
    $element['crop']    = 1;
}

$image_sizes = array(
    'shop_featured_image_size' => array( intval( $element['width'] ), intval( $element['height'] ), ( $element['crop'] === 1 ? true : false ) ),
);

return array_merge( $image_sizes , $images );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're treating `$element` as though it's an array without setting it as one first.

Change this:

```
$element['width']   = "160";
$element['height'] = "160";
$element['crop']    = 1;
```

To:

```
$element = array(
    'width'  => 160,
    'height' => 160,
    'crop'   => 1,
);
```

As long as `$element` is an array you can continue to append elements in the way you were originally, e.g. `$element['extra'] = ...`.

Comment: I made the change but am still getting the same errors. I never made any change to this code originally... all that I did was change the size of the width for the single product featured image (466 to 700). I read online that it could be some kind of interference from another WordPress/WooCommerce/Theme function that is being called prior to, or after this particular function? (My PHP knowledge, as you can tell, is severely limited, so I apologize if that doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was an issue with the theme itself and WooCommerce. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly solved the problem ? I am having the same issue and I don't know what to do now...

Answer (score 0):

Never change/hack the woocommerce core.

In my case, all I had to do was resetting my image size settings in the Customizer. Navigate to WooCommerce -> Product Images.

Change the size, save, change the size back to your desired size and save again.